# Meteor.wrapAsync and NPM package (Steam)

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I’m trying to build a simple STEAM bot for my Meteor application but I hit a roadblock as I can’t figure out how to correctly use Meteor.wrapAsync in order to correctly display the results on the front.

My code looks like this:

**1. SERVER**

```
import SteamUser from 'steam-user';
import SteamTotp from 'steam-totp';
import SteamCommunity from 'steamcommunity';
import TradeOfferManager from 'steam-tradeoffer-manager';

tradeBot1 = Meteor.settings.SteamTradeBot1;

// Vars
const client = new SteamUser();

const community = new SteamCommunity();

const manager = new TradeOfferManager({
    steam: client,
    community: community,
    language: 'en'
});

const logOnOptionsBot1 = {
    accountName: tradeBot1.username,
    password: tradeBot1.password,
    twoFactorCode: SteamTotp.generateAuthCode(tradeBot1.sharedSecret)
};

// Bot login
client.logOn(logOnOptionsBot1);

// After login set bot as online
client.on('loggedOn', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(){
    console.log('Steam Trade Bot #1 online.');
    client.setPersona(SteamUser.Steam.EPersonaState.Online);
}));

// Set cookies
client.on('webSession', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(sessionid, cookies){
    manager.setCookies(cookies);
    community.setCookies(cookies);
}));


Meteor.methods({
    "sendTradeOffer": function(tradeUrl, winId, uid){
        try {
            var assetId = "1111111111";
            var appid = "730";
            var itemName = "itemnamexxxxxxx";

            // Create new offer
            // https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steam-tradeoffer-manager/wiki/TradeOfferManager
            const offer = manager.createOffer(tradeUrl);

            // Add item to offer
            offer.addMyItem({
                'assetid': assetId,
                'appid': appid,
                'contextid': 2,
                'amount': 1
            });

            // Set custom message
            offer.setMessage(`Congrats! You got "${itemName}"! Ref: "` + winId + `"`);

            // Send offer
            offer.send(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, status){
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return err;
                } else {
                    console.log(`Sent offer. Status: ${status}. Waiting for auto confirmation ...`);

                    // Set a 5 second delay before confirmation
                    Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
                        community.acceptConfirmationForObject(tradeBot1.indentitySecret, offer.id, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err){

                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                return err;
                            } else {
                                console.log("Offer confirmed.");
                                console.log("Sent Steam item with ID: " + assetId);

                                // Update data in mongo
                                // .....

                                // Return something to the front ???
                                var outcome = {
                                    message: "Trade offer sent!"
                                }

                                return outcome;

                            }

                        }));
                    }, 5000);
                }

            }));

        } catch(error){
            console.log(error);
            return error;
        }
    }

});
```

**2. FRONT**

```
'submit form#send-trade': function(event, t){
    event.preventDefault();

    var tradeUrl = $("#user-trade-url").val();
    var winId = "winidxxxxxxx";
    var uid = "uidxxxxxxx";

    Meteor.call("sendTradeOffer", tradeUrl, winId, uid, function(error, result){
        if (error){
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(result);

        }
    });
 }
```

What this should do is:

- Bot login - working
- Set bot status to online after login - working
- User enters their tradeUrl on the front - working
- Meteor method sendTradeOffer is executed - working
- Offer is sent and confirmed - working
- Return error or result in the front - not working

Console.logs on server work just fine but I can't return anything to the front, it's always undefined.

I’ve searched around quite a bit this past couple of days and from my understanding I should be using Meteor.wrapAsync to correctly return either an error or a result but I simply can’t wrap my head around it. How would Meteor.wrapAsync would apply in my case?

Any help is much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: I can't find any `wrapAsync` in your code!?

Comment: @Jankapunkt That is correct, as I'm not sure where to use it or how to approach this at all. I assume I need to wrap `offer.send` and `community.acceptConfirmationForObject` only? Although I don't understand how to be entirely honest.

Comment: @Jankapunkt To add to my previous comment I've just tried `"wrapTest": function (tradeUrl, winId, uid) {
  var syncFunc = Meteor.wrapAsync(sendTradeOffer); 
  var result = syncFunc(tradeUrl, winId, uid);
  console.log(result);
 }` but I get `Exception while invoking method 'wrapTest' ReferenceError: sendTradeOffer is not defined` although both are in the same JS file? The `wrapTest` method is right below the above example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits for this answer goes to [@robfallows](https://forums.meteor.com/u/robfallows) from the official Meteor forums:

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendTradeOffer(tradeUrl, winId, uid) {
    // Create new offer
    const offer = manager.createOffer(tradeUrl);
    // Meter.wrapAsync
    const offerSend = Meteor.wrapAsync(offer.send, offer);
    const communityAcceptConfirmationForObject = Meteor.wrapAsync(community.acceptConfirmationForObject, community);
    try {
      const assetId = '1111111111';
      const appid = '730';
      const itemName = 'itemnamexxxxxxx';

      // Add item to offer
      offer.addMyItem({
        'assetid': assetId,
        'appid': appid,
        'contextid': 2,
        'amount': 1
      });

      // Set custom message
      offer.setMessage(`Congrats! You got ${itemName}! Ref: ${winId}`);

      // Send offer
      const status = offerSend(); // will throw error on failure
      console.log(`Sent offer. Status: ${status}. Waiting for auto confirmation ...`);

      // Set a 5 second delay before confirmation
      Meteor._sleepForMs(5000); // Fiber based inline sleep
      communityAcceptConfirmationForObject(tradeBot1.indentitySecret, offer.id);  // will throw error on failure

      console.log('Offer confirmed.');
      console.log('Sent Steam item with ID: ', assetId);

      // Update data in mongo
      // .....

      // Return something to the front ???
      const outcome = {
        message: 'Trade offer sent!'
      }

      return outcome;

    } catch (err) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('oops', err.message); // return error to client
    }
  },
});
```

As per his notes:

- All callbacks removed to use Fibers. That means the code works
  sequentially and the return object is available exactly where it
  appears to be.
- Meteor.wrapAsync used for the two calls which seem to
  need it.
- Tidied up for ES6 (ESLint is a harsh mistress!)